# How to create an image in c++ with an 2d rgb array?

Tags: c++

Well I'm using a restAPI to get a 2d numpy rgb-array from python and I want to create and image from it using c++ .Do you have any idea how to do it? or Do you know a similar library of numpy fro c++?

Comment: What kind of image? Do you want to save it to disk, display it, something else?

Comment: png or bmp and i want to display it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its pretty simple to create a bitmap (.bmp extensions).

You can either use a library, like this one:
https://github.com/ArashPartow/bitmap. A library with a narrow use case is usually pretty readable. The logic is all contained in a single hpp file in this case. Looking at it, its a little complex because it handles a ton of different cases.

Or you can just do it yourself. Look up how to write a binary bitmap header and use fstream to write it out to a file. You'll want to use the binary options when opening the file for writing `ios::out | ios::binary`. You can find the details of the bitmap header and file format here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

By the way, Wikipedia has many decent references on binary file formats with bit-by-bit tables.

For an extremely naive implementation that does not handle a bunch of different formats, I've done this in the past.

BitmapFileHeader.h

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdint>

#pragma pack(push, 2)
struct BitmapFileHeader
{
    char header[2]{'B', 'M'};
    uint32_t fileSize;
    uint32_t reserved{};
    uint32_t dataOffset;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

BitmapInfoHeader.h

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>

#pragma pack(push, 2)
struct BitmapInfoHeader
{
    uint32_t headerSize{ 40 };
    uint32_t width{ 0 };
    uint32_t height{ 0 };
    uint16_t planes{ 1 };
    uint16_t bitsPerPixel{ 24 };
    uint32_t compression{ 0 };
    uint32_t dataSize{ 0 };
    uint32_t horizontalResolution{ 2400 };
    uint32_t verticalResolution{ 2400 };
    uint32_t colors{ 0 };
    uint32_t importantColors{ 0 };
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Bitmap.h

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>
#include "BitmapFileHeader.h"
#include "BitmapInfoHeader.h"


using namespace std;

class Bitmap
{
private:
    int m_width{ 0 };
    int m_height{ 0 };
    unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> m_pixels{ nullptr };

public:
    struct RBG {
        uint8_t r;
        uint8_t b;
        uint8_t g;
    };

    Bitmap(int width, int height) : m_width(width), 
        m_height(height), m_pixels(new uint8_t[width * height * sizeof(RBG)]{}) {};

    void setPixel(int, int, RBG);
    void setDimensions(int, int);
    int getSize();
    bool write(string);

    ~Bitmap();
};
```

Bitmap.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Bitmap.h"

using namespace std;

void Bitmap::setPixel(int x, int y, RBG color)
{
    uint8_t *pixel = m_pixels.get();

    pixel = pixel + ((y * sizeof(RBG)) * m_width) + (x * sizeof(RBG));

    // little endian
    pixel[0] = color.b;
    pixel[1] = color.g;
    pixel[2] = color.r;
}

void Bitmap::setDimensions(int w, int h)
{
    m_width = w;
    m_height = h;
}

int Bitmap::getSize()
{
    return m_width * m_height * sizeof(RBG);
}

bool Bitmap::write(string filename)
{   
    BitmapFileHeader fileHeader; 
    BitmapInfoHeader infoHeader;

    fileHeader.fileSize = sizeof(BitmapFileHeader) + sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader) + getSize();
    fileHeader.dataOffset = sizeof(BitmapFileHeader) + sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader);

    infoHeader.width = m_width;
    infoHeader.height = m_height;

    ofstream file; 
    file.open(filename, ios::out | ios::binary);

    if (!file)
    {
        return false;
    }

    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&fileHeader), sizeof(fileHeader));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&infoHeader), sizeof(infoHeader));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(m_pixels.get()), getSize());

    file.close();

    return true;
}

Bitmap::~Bitmap()
{
    cout << "bitmap destroyed" << endl;
}
```